# Android Samsung Young 4.1.2 S6310 enable USB debugging

Tags: android, usb-debugging

When I try to enable it it's just grayed out, I have tried disconnecting the USB, installing the drivers, turning on the developer options yet it just remains grayed out. I can only connect to my PC via MTP and PTP and neither enable USD debugging.

How do I enable USB debugging on Samsung Young S6310 running Android 4.1.2?

Comment: That's a shame... good luck fixing it. Did you have a question?

Comment: How do I enable USB debugging on Android Young 4.1.2?

Comment: there's no such thing as "Android Young". Perhaps you mean the Samsung Young phone, which happens to run Android?

Comment: Ah yes sorry, 4AM here haha

Comment: Did you eventually solve it?

Answer (score 1):

At the top of the "Developer options" screen, there's an on/off toggle to enable its features.
Turn it on, then you should be able to enable USB debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try going to "About" then clicking on the model number 5 to 10 times?

Comment: I clicked on the build number like 20 times and nothing happened, I even tried to click on kernel version, baseband version, android version and model number, nothing happened except the android screen popped up when I clicked twice on android version.

Comment: Just restarted once more just to be sure, still greyed out.

Comment: Now I'm confused on your question did you unlock developer options but USB is grey or is developer options not unlocking?

Comment: The USB debugging option is just greyed out, I cannot enable it, it does show up under Debugging however. Thanks for all your help.